# CEdit edit_box has hwnd null

Tags: c++, mfc

I have CEdit control on my MFC dialog:

```
class ODBC_Dialog : public CDialog
{
CEdit sql_edit_;
};
```

but that sql_edit_ variable later in the ctor has its hWnd = 0x00000000;

I suspect that it should have some value other than that and because it has basically nullptr value I cannot use it and I'm getting runtime error when trying to use it. Am I supposed to initialize this variable somehow?

Comment: when you added it as a control variable using the class wizard, MFC should have done the necessary plumbing for you to link the member variable with the resource identifier of the control. For example there should be a DDX_Control mapping in the ::DoDataExchange method.

Comment: @dlatikay yes indeed there is : DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, sql_edit_);

Comment: try two things: 1) make sure the IDC_EDIT1 value is actually the one assigned to the control in resource.h, those things sometimes tend to get out of sync when they're moved around
2) set a breakpoint on that DDC_Control... line and check in the debugger if it is hit before the point where you expect the variable to be initialized. Do not expect this to be as early as the ctor call, it will be later.

Comment: @dlatikay interestingly, DoDataExchange is called only after I click OK on this dialog. Any ideas why?!?!?

Comment: do you ever use the sql_edit_ variable in code? it might have been optimized away as an unused variable, fooling the debugger.
you will have an ::OnInitDialog function. Try to assign something to your edit box there, like ´sql_edit_.SetWindowText(L"some text")´

Comment: @dlatikay hi, thanks for your help. I solved it but your comments gave me hints as to what can be possibly wrong. the answer is that in OnInitDialog in my Dialog class I am also supposed to call Parent::OnInitDialog. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the control variable is mentioned in ::DoDataExchange. Check if resource identifier matches that of the control. If

```
::DoDataExchange()
```

is not called, MFC framework lifecycle may be broken for example by not calling the base of an overridden ::On...Dialog... member function:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/872b8e39-db53-4635-87a8-42b2235a43d9/dodataexchange-not-called?forum=vclanguage

Comment: yep, Parent::OnInitDialog must be called